# Picasso: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null

Tags: java, android, picasso

Hey Guys having  a bit of trouble with trying to put a image into the image view using picasso.

getting the error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null on this line of code

```
            .into(UserProfilePhoto);
```

Here is the full code
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final AppCompatActivity activity = UserProfileActivity.this;

```
private int avatarSize;
private String profilePhoto;


@BindView(R.id.UserProfilePhoto)
ImageView UserProfilePhoto;

@BindView(R.id.UserProfileTabs)
TabLayout UserProfileTabs;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.Bind(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    this.avatarSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.user_profile_photo);
    this.profilePhoto = getString(R.string.user_profile_photo);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(profilePhoto)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.circle)
            .resize(avatarSize, avatarSize)
            .centerCrop()
            .transform(new TransformCircle())
            .into(UserProfilePhoto);
```

The imageview on the xml is the same as defined on here so i have no idea why its not working.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ie.coffeepal.coffeepal/ie.coffeepal.coffeepal.activities.UserProfileActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                                      at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                                                                      at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                                      at ie.coffeepal.coffeepal.activities.UserProfileActivity.onCreate(UserProfileActivity.java:49)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using ButterKnife but never call ButterKnife.bind(this) method so your ImageView is null at the moment when you try to load an image.

UPD
call ButterKnife.bind(this) after setContentView() method

Answer (score 2):

From the [Docmentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) of `ButterKnife`

you forgot to call `ButterKnife.bind(this);`

so your `imageview` is null which gives exception in `picasso`

**Use**

```
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);   //add this
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I have updated, built and re-ran the code, but the error is still occuring for some reason. I have updated the post with the new error

Comment: you should use getresources().getstring()  to get the url profilePhoto

Comment: also make sure your layout and imageview id's are correct.